# Folder size as variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to compare a folder size with a size limit. When I try to run the script, it gives me the error 'integer expression expected'.

```
limit=200
foldersize=$(du /home/user1/testfolder)

if [ "$foldersize" -le "limit" ];
then
  echo "Folder size is small"
else
  echo "Folder size is big"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, it's a typo in `if [ "$foldersize" -le "limit" ];` you should add `$` before `limit`.

Comment: And `du` command output not only folder size but also folder name you have to cut it before comparing the size.

Comment: If you would run your code with `set -x` turned on, you would immediately spot these errors by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size needs to be `read` from the `du` `< <(command)` stream, with   tab and new-line as fields separator and no records delimiter, because the output from `dc` contains multiple lines to be read as a single record.

Here is an example of output from `du --bytes --summarize --total /home/user1/testfolder`:

```
4954626   /home/user1/testfolder
4954626   total
```

Your code modified:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i limit=200000
declare -- test_folder=/home/user1/testfolder

declare -i folder_size
IFS=$' \t\n' read -r -d ''  _ _ folder_size _ < <(
  du --bytes --summarize --total "$test_folder"
)

if [[ "$folder_size" -le "$limit" ]];
then
  printf 'Folder size is small\n'
else
  printf 'Folder size is big\n'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
limit=200
folder_size=$(du ~user1/testfolder|cut -d ' ' -f 1)

if (( folder_size <= limit ))
then
  echo Folder size is small
else
  echo Folder size is big
fi
```

or, without variables,

```
if (( $(du ~user1/testfolder|cut -d ' ' -f 1) <= 200 ))
then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
du -s /home/user1/testfolder |cut -f1
```

instead of :

```
du /home/user1/testfolder
```